# Kali Linux and Windows 8: Switching MBR to GRUB

Tags: linux, windows-8, grub, multi-boot

I'm trying to install [Kali Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux) (amd64) alongside Windows 8 (x64). I have prepared suitable free disk space (the second and third partition were formated to [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) (the first, the primary, NTFS)), and I placed Kali Linux there. The last thing done by Installator was to prepare [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB). My Windows 8 was succesfully identified (as Windows Vista) and whole process ended without any errors. Unfortunatelly, when I'm booting my PC now, it still uses [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), so that the newly installed Kali Linux is not recognized.

I tried proceeding with the installation twice. Always with same results.

How do I successfully replace MBR with Kali Linux's GRUB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only used the Kali Linux graphical installer, maybe you could try and install GRUB manually with:

```
grub-install /dev/sdX

grub-mkconfig /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If GRUB is not working, you can still add Kali Linux to the Windows boot menu with the program [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). How to do it is explained in *[Dual-boot Windows 7 and Kali Linux](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/24/dual-boot-windows-7-and-kali-linux/2/)* at step number 3.

Comment: What is /dev/sdX supposed to point to? The boot partition, or the Kali partition?

Comment: The boot partition.